# does openni support 2d camera

Tags: android, algorithm, openni, pose-estimation, keypoint

Our company want to develop a android app to analyse 2D camera's video frame. By integrating openni sdk, app can get human body keypoints. With keypoints, app find the hand keypoints and hand's location in frame. But after our research, we now find some problems:

- openni's repository in github didn't maintain for 6 years.
- Can we use openni to get human's body keypoints by 2D picture or frame? And how to do.
- If openni can't, is there any other way to solve this in android?

Comment: Have you seen: https://github.com/google/mediapipe

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for your advice. After i use the demo, I think mediapipe is what i want. I am now working to adapt the demo to my project, though there are some uncompitable issue to solve. Because i usually work on android app develop, so the aar file help me a lot.

Comment: @MorrisonChang from the site(https://google.github.io/mediapipe/) i know that 
```
MediaPipe is currently in alpha at v0.7
```
It means it isn't stable and easy to use. In the same  time, our project use usb camera. the mediapipe support front and back but usb camera.  the code is difficult to adapt for usb camera.